# Writing data from background task

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I what to change variable in localsetting in my app from bagground task. I have wroute such code fjr background task:

```
namespace TestTask
    {
        public sealed class Task :IBackgroundTask
        {
            public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
            {
                BackgroundTaskDeferral _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
                var storage = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
                int i = (int)storage.Values["var"];
                i++;

                storage.Values["var"] = i;

                _deferral.Complete();
            }
        }
    }
```

And that task read data, but cannot write. And Localsettings parametr isreadonly is true.
Maybe there is another way to solve my issue?

Comment: You surely should be able to write to *ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings* in Background Task. As I've checked on my sample it works just fine. Why do you think that the value hadn't changed? Can you show the code responsible for checking it? Also aren't you redefining the value in your app?

Comment: On mainPage i have several buttons, one button make the same work as background task, other button show result on textbox. `var storage = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings; int i =(int)storage.Values["var"]; textbox1.text=i.toString();`

Comment: Couple of questions more: What kind of BTask you have? How are you testing your BTask - *Lifecycle events*? Are you sure your BTask is being run? Are you setting this "var" somewhere else? What is it's initial value and where you set it?

Comment: I use lifecycleevents for testing. So I think if BTask appears lifecycleevents it that BTask is ran. Also i make breakpoit in beginning of y Btask. What does mean BTask type? Trigger is TimeTrigger(15,false). I set var from buttonclick event, initial value is 0 from mainform. On the mainform i also have button that inceese var.  I'm sorry that i cannot show all my code now(i'm not at home). I will do it later.

Comment: By BTask type I meant if it's audio/TimeTriggered/Maintenance and so on. I've also tested it with TimeTriggered task. I'll wait for more code. Maybe it will be possible that you share the sample working project?

Comment: Here is link to sample project [SampleProject](http://1drv.ms/1BoSyhb). The problem is that app's localsettings and Btask Localsettings are not the same localsettengs

Comment: In your sample project as I can see there is a mistake? - in BTask you are using RoamingSettings and in MainApp LocalSettings - they are not the same.

Comment: Oh, at first my attampt there was Localsettings everwhere, and it disn't work, but after i try another ways to solve my issue. I dond't know what was at first time, but now it works fine. Thank you very much for your help, and your time whitch you waste for me!!!

Comment: I have one question. This Btask would work only when app in background, and does not work when it is closed, does it? Or does it  work like ScheduledTaskAgent in WP7.5?

Comment: It should also work when app is closed/foreground/background.

Comment: I just have tested this sample a couple of hours on my wp8.1 device, and data in local storage does not changed. But when I call Btask from lifecycle data Change. Please can you check my code again,maybe something  else wrong?

Comment: It's now allright. Jast needed uninstall app adm restart device befoere new deploy on device. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the value of `isreadonly` to false